# why does my work look completely different on mobile to how it's designed?

Tags: android, css, mobile, responsive-design

So I've been trying to learn more about responsive design. I've started playing about on my computer with a tiny project with a mobile first approach. I scaled my browser down small and styled the layout correctly. Using % for widths and REM for fonts. I thought wow this is easy

However, when I went to look at my work on an actual mobile the layout positions were fine but every feature/element on the page was showing up tiny. So the navigation menu was coming up really small compared to how it looked in my browser.

Why is this? The browser I use is chrome and the mobile android.

Comment: You probably forgot to set initial scale in your meta tags:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`
You can read about it e.g. on Bootstrap docs page: [Overview - Mobile](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)

Comment: thanks great I thought I'll go check it out

Comment: also to test how it looks on mobile right click..inspect element..top left there is a mobile icon ..click it and refresh page..you can also select different devices